# encryption and decryption with ASCII values

Tags: python, encryption, ascii

Im trying to write a program that encrypts and decrypts with ASCII values.  The code I have currently only outputs the first letter of the string. The code below only shos the encryption and decryption functions

```
#define the encryption
def encrypt(text,shift):
  en=""
  for i in text:
      if(ord(i))>=65 and (ord(i)<=90):
          temp=(ord(i)+shift)
          if temp>90:
              temp=temp%90+64
              en=en+chr(temp)
      elif(ord(i))>=97 and (ord(i)<=122):
          temp=(ord(i)+shift)
          if temp>122:
              temp=temp%122+96
          en=en+chr(temp)
      else:
          en=en+chr(ord(i)+shift)
      return en

#define the decryption
def decrypt(text,shift):
    p=encrypt(text,shift)
    de=""
    for i in p:
        if((ord(i))>=65) and (ord(i))<=90:
            de=de+chr((ord(i) - shift-65) % 26 + 65)
        elif((ord(i))>=97) and (ord(i))<=122:
            de=de+chr((ord(i) - shift - 97) % 26 + 97)
        else:
            de=de+chr(ord(i)-shift)
    return de
```

Comment: No, no, you cannot do `% 90` or `% 122`. First you need to subtract the value of `ord('a')` or `ord('A')` (i.e. calculate the zero based index in the defined alphabet, in this case the ABC), then you perform the addition or subtraction with the shift, then you perform the `% 26` where 26 is the size of the alphabet / ABC.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your first function, encrypt, is set to return only the final value of **en**, you need to de-indent your return to your **for** loop level to return the full string.